# How to parse HTML and retreive multiline text

Tags: php

I would like to fetch some text from an HTML file. I tried using the following librairie https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser.

Here is the content I want to parse :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" height="30" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"> 
                        <a href="https://google.fr" style="color:red" moz-do-not-send="true">TEXT</a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color:green" width="36" align="right">
                        <a href="google.fr" moz-do-not-send="true">LINK</a>            
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:100%" height="14"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="15"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table style="color:red" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="3%"> </td>
                    <td style="font-size:18px">TEXT TO FETCH
                    TEXT TO FETCH
                    </td>
                    <td width="3%"> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:10px;"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:10px;" height="10"> </td>
</tr>
```

I'm expecting to fetch the both "TEXT TO FETCH" on the multiline.

My PHP script :

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load('content');
$a = $dom->find('tr>td>table>tbody>tr>td');

var_dump($a);


foreach($a as $b){
   $child   = $b->firstChild();
   $sibling = $child->nextSibling();
   print_r($sibling);
}
```

Here is the result of the script :

```
object(PHPHtmlParser\Dom\Collection)#1372 (1) {
  ["collection":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

If I use `tr > td > table > tbody` I have the following :

```
string(2) "  "
```

Comment: Does `$dom->find('tr>td>table>tbody>tr>td')[0]` do anything?

Comment: I tried and I get `NULL`

Comment: Try `$dom->find('tr>td>table>tbody>tr>td')[0]->text; `

Comment: @MosesSchwartz I got an error `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'text' of non-object in test.php on line 49`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element in the selector has to be surrounded with spaces. The following selector selects all text of `td` elements:

```
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load($html);
$a = $dom->find('tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td');


foreach($a as $b){
    $child   = $b->firstChild();
    var_dump($child->text);
}
```

Result:

```
/index.php:58:string ' ' (length=1)
/index.php:58:string ' ' (length=1)
/index.php:58:string ' ' (length=1)
/index.php:58:string 'TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH ' (length=28)
/index.php:58:string ' ' (length=1)
```

Because of the invalid dom not all `td` nodes are found. The following script can be used to extract the text:

```
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load($html);
$a = $dom->find('tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td');


foreach($a as $b){
    var_dump(strip_tags($b->innerHTML));
}
```

result:

```
/index.php:497:string '         TEXT TEXT TEXT        ' (length=31)
/index.php:497:string 'TEXT TEXT TEXT ' (length=15)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '         Date:  TEXT      TEXT  TEXT      TEXT  00000000    TEXT:  TEXT    ' (length=75)
/index.php:497:string '    TEXT TEXT       ' (length=20)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '      TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH      ' (length=165)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string 'TEXT TEXT TEXT ' (length=15)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string '                    TEXT    TEXT                  TEXT   TEXT                  TEXT                  TEXT                 TEXT TEXT               ' (length=146)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string ' ' (length=1)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string 'TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT. TEXT TEXTTEXT. ' (length=56)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
/index.php:497:string 'TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ' (length=44)
/index.php:497:string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: I'm not retreiving the data I want to fetch

Comment: what part is missing? It outputs "TEXT TO FETCH TEXT TO FETCH". @executable

Comment: I was able to extract all text, please checkout the updated answer @executable

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the explanation, it make sense to me now

Comment: No worries! Good luck with your project @executable